# Generate test coverage information from pyunit unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, python-unittest

I have some pyunit unit tests for a simple command line programme I'm writing. Is it possible for me to generate test coverage numbers? I want to see what lines aren't being covered by my tests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I regularly use Ned Batchelder's [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/coverage.html) tool for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your tests with [testoob](http://code.google.com/p/testoob/) you can get a coverage report with `--coverage`. Can install with easy_install. No changes to your tests necessary:

```
testoob alltests.py --coverage
```